# Get total size in bytes of content of iframe with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe in my page, can I get the total size in bytes of the content loaded by the iframe. I'm referring to something similar to what we see in network activity when we do inspect element in browser and at the bottom it shows (**333kb** transferred).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the iframe content since it would be cross-site scripting, which is prohibited for security 
reasons.

Trying to access the iframe content using javascript will result in access denied errors.